# Double of a manifold

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a connected $n$-manifold with a non-empty boundary. The double of it is given by
$$
D(M) = M\,\,\,\cup_f\,\,\, M
$$
where $f:\partial M\to\partial M$ is an identity map. I have to show that $D(M)$ is connected. Since it is a quotient space I had an idea to consider a connected space $X$ together with a quotient map $q:X\to D(M)$ but clearly $X = M\sqcup M$ is not a good candidate since it is disconnected. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: $D(M)$ is not connected unless $M$ is. Did you mean to assume $M$ is connected?

Comment: Assuming $M$ is connected, $D(M)$ is the union of two connected sets with nontrivial intersection. So by a standard lemma, it is connected.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: thanks, $M$ should be connected.

Comment: @JimConant: you're right. Could you please put this comment as an answer just expanding it a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are assuming $M$ is connected. The double $D(M)$ is equal to a union of two copies of $M$ that intersect in $\partial M\neq \emptyset$. On the other hand, it is a standard lemma in topology that the union of two connected sets that has a nontrivial intersection is connected. See for example Munkres's **Topology** (second edition) Theorem 23.3.